# How to execute 2 if/else statements in gsp g:each?

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a code in gsp as:

```
<g:each in="model" status="i" var="variable">
    if(condition1){
    //code1
    return;
    }
    else{
    //else for code1
    }
    if(condition2){
    //code2
    return;
    }
    else{
    //else for code2
    }
</g:each>
```

I want to execute both the if conditions in g:each, and break-out only when both conditions are satisfied. But what happens is, if some condition gets true in first if statement, then it breaks out of g:each.
Any solutions?

Comment: What happens if you wrap it into a function, then call it.

Comment: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/if.html

Comment: @Manu:  I cannot wrap it into a function since I'm using variable from g:each in if statement, and that variable won't be accessible outside g:each

Comment: @cfrick: what will be the difference if i use <g:if> instead of javascript if() ? i need to compare values from textfield and model, hence i used if().

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is your gsp code is generating blocks of JavaScript code; a set of `if` blocks for each object in the `model` collection. It's not actually "breaking out" from the `g:each` because by the time the JavaScript code runs the `g:each` had long finished running. The `g:each` runs at the server **without running the if blocks** and the JavaScript code runs at the browser.

Take a look at the generated HTML. I suspect your bug has to do with Grails variables not resolved into the JavaScript code, and maybe some logical errors. Those return statements look suspicious.